# How to calculate if a shape is under another in pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x, collision-detection, pyglet

I'm making an endless runner using pyglet.
[image: The game]
I'm trying to determine the height of the floor under the player. Every floor is a class:

```py
class Floor():
    def __init__(self, width, height, offset, batch=None):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.floor = shapes.Rectangle(offset, 0, self.width, self.height, color=(9, 197, 0), batch=batch)
    def move(self, amount):
        self.floor.x -= amount
```

So i added a method to the class to calculate if the floor is under the player (the player is also a shape):

```py
    def under_player(self, player):
        if player.x <= self.floor.x and self.floor.x + self.width >= player.x:
            return True
        return False
```

To calculate now the floor height the player is under, i made this function (floors is a list of `Floor` classes):

```py
def calc_under_floor():
    global floors, player
    for floor in floors:
        if floor.under_player(player):
            return floor.height
    return -100
```

The problem is that the condition in `under_player` for checking the if the player is under this floor is wrong. I can't find a working solution. Is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: why in uder_player method you check it by X coordinate?

Comment: The floor or the player?

Comment: what are you trying to check if you use X coordinates? Does the code work? ```if player.x <= self.floor.x and self.floor.x + self.width >= player.x:```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. Here is a screenshot https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/694553611639717888/793402133599748136/unknown.png?width=633&height=475

Comment: can you give us your whole code, so I could represent it in my computer and test it all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226550/discussion-between-yellowking-and-crackanddie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I found the solution. At least it works :)

```py
    def under_player(self, player):
        if player.x + 50 >= self.floor.x and player.x <= self.floor.x + self.floor.width:
            return True
        return False
```